# Table content does not display when using javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, datatables

Below is my code but it does not work yet. What should I do to fix it?

See in particular `function showtbl();`

**My real problem is in `function showtbl();` which does not display the contents of the table.**

```js
var tampilqr = function (kode) {
    var url = 'http://www.playstore.co.id/p/download.html?qr='
    var urlfix = url + kode
    var keluar = '<a style="float:right;color:#999;text-decoration:none;background:#fff;width:20px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" onclick="rem();">X</a><br>'
    var cek = keluar + '<iframe src="' + urlfix + '"></iframe>'
    if (jscd.os == 'Android') {
        window.location.href = urlfix;
    } else {
        uglipop({
            class: 'dl',
            source: 'html',
            content: cek
        });
    }
}

var tampilss = function (kode) {
    var url = 'https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/detil.html?ss='
    var urlfix = url + kode
    var keluar = '<a style="float:right;color:#999;text-decoration:none;background:#fff;width:20px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" onclick="rem();">X</a><br>'
    var cek = keluar + '<iframe src="' + urlfix + '"></iframe>'
    uglipop({
        class: 'ss',
        source: 'html',
        content: cek
    });
}

var rem = function () {
    remove();
}

function tulis() {
    document.getElementById("cari").placeholder = "cari aplikasi";
    if (on_index = true) {
        window.location = window.location.pathname + '?apps='
    }
}

function showtbl() {
    var img = "<img src='logo/"
    var imgt = ".png'/>"
    var li = "<br /> Link: <a href='?apps="
    var lin = "'>http://playstore.co.id/?apps="
    var link = "</a><br /> Terbit: "
    var b = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='tampilss(&quot;"
    var bt = "&quot;);'>Screenshoot</button><br><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='tampilqr(&quot;"
    var btn = "&quot;);'>Download</button>"
    var A1 = "ss-clothes"
    var A2 = "korselindo"
    var A3 = "real-hiphop-shop"

    /* if HTML, it must be:
    <tr>
        <td><img src="logo/ss-clothes.png" /></td>
        <td>SS-Clothes<br /> Link: <a href="http://playstore.co.id?apps=ss-clothes">http://playstore.co.id?apps=ss-clothes</a><br /> Terbit: 23-06-2015</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="tampilss(&quot;ss-clothes&quot;);" type="button">Screenshoot</button><br />
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="tampilqr(&quot;ss-clothes&quot;);" type="button">Download</button></td>
    </tr>
    */

    var values = new Array(3);
    values[1] = [img + A1 + imgt, A1 + li + A1 + lin + A1 + link, b + A1 + bt + A1 + btn];
    values[2] = [img + A2 + imgt, A2 + li + A2 + lin + A2 + link, b + A2 + bt + A2 + btn];
    values[3] = [img + A3 + imgt, A3 + li + A3 + lin + A3 + link, b + A3 + bt + A3 + btn];

    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

    // IE7 only supports appending rows to tbody
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // for each outer array row
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");

        // for each inner array cell
        // create td then text, append
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var txt = document.createElement("span");
            txt.innerHTML = values[i][j];
            td.appendChild(txt);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        // append row to table
        // IE7 requires append row to tbody, append tbody to table
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        myTable.appendChild(tbody);
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download Aplikasi</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="Toko aplikasi android Indonesia, apptoko, download aplikasi android .apk, appstore alternatif Google play store android market">
    <link href="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src='https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/js/modernizr.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link href="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script async="" src="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script async="" src="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/js/os.js"></script>

    <link href="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/css/uglipop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script async="" src="https://dfe4876b91450c3efbab76e8d43c4a665e738138-www.googledrive.com/host/0B94BKN-oncxmfllMNlZkWGJTaF9QWmtLOVktR3djU3B0NGJuTFVwS2tDMS1jYzZkNEN6Y00/js/uglipop.js"></script>

</head>

<body onLoad="tulis();showtbl();">

    <div id="atas">
        <a href="javascript:window.location.replace('http://www.playstore.co.id?apps=')"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-UON5Z5IIOus/VdH_gr8XRXI/AAAAAAAAAbY/Q-I4QfbZr9U/s1600/playstore-indonesia-logo.gif" /></a>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Logo</th>
                <th>Nama App</th>
                <th>Tindakan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("img").error(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });

            var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "oSearch": {
                    "sSearch": $.urlParam('apps'),
                    responsive: true
                },
            });
        });

        $.urlParam = function (name) {

            var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            return results && results[1].replace(/(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z ]+|\s+$)/g, ' ');
            return results && results[1].replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

            if (!results) {
                return '//';
            }
            return results[1] || '';
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**My real problem is in `function showtbl();` which does not display the contents of the table.**

Please run the code. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a dynamic table. What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Please run code above, table row does not appear when I place row+column content in javascript. @Michael Laszlo

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you get an answer. There's so much code to look at! Why don't you create a simplified page and post that? If anything, it'll help you debug the issue.

Comment: If I know the answer I certainly would not make this question. If you have a solution please answer. @Adrian Lynch

Comment: What Adrian is saying, it is not our job to read through your code because that is wordy and time consuming. If you would like to get a quick answer it helps to create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Like the others say: too long, didn't read.

Comment: Sorry, if I do not understand what your point, I am not fluent in English. and I am also a new member here. I just expect to get answers to my problems here. My real problem is in `function showtbl()` which does not display the contents of the table. @Adjit

Comment: This is a pretty messy code. Since you are using jquery at some point, try refactoring it, and maybe an answer would follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My real problem is in function showtbl(); which does not display the
>   contents of the table.

If you remove the irrelevant empty `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>` it works  :

**http://jsfiddle.net/yujpozf9/1/**

dataTables does not like multiple `<tbody>` elements, and certainly not `<tbody>` elements with an odd number of columns (like none).

Also move `responsive: true` out to where it belongs and remove the trailing `'` - you seem to have a lot of focus on IE7, trailing quotes is a IE7-killer.

```
var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
   responsive: true,
   "oSearch": {
      //"sSearch": $.urlParam('apps')
   }
});
```

have commented out `$.urlParam` since this is not the main issue, and I not fully understand what you are trying to do. Your code is one of the most peculiar uses of dataTables I have ever seen (no offense!) - try read about column rendering, I think you will be much happier doing it this way -> **https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html** - the official examples in general.

Also, instead of using google drive, you can use the dataTables CDN - much easier to maintain and change versions. I have noticed you are using v1.10.2 :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for willing to answer, `$ .urlParam` intended when a user type a url with parameter eg: [http://playstore.co.id?apps=ss-clothes](http://playstore.co.id?apps=ss-clothes) it will automatically filter the data based on the keywords **ss clothes**. Is there a solution if it is included without messing up other code?

Comment: Hi, I have successfully completed my problem with revising the code into `showtbl();

$(document).ready(function(){

 var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
     responsive: true,
     "oSearch": {
        "sSearch": $.urlParam('apps')
    }
});
} );` Thank you @davidkonrad

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, datatables plugin need well-formatted table to work properly. You need thead and tbody tags as it's specified in the doc (read it carefully : https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation). Once it's done you don't have to write all that code to filter and display what you want.

Comment: I has added `thead` & `tbody`. but, it does not work yet.